# How do you scan for available WiFi networks from Windows IoT Background App?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-iot-core

Anybody know a work around for scanning for WiFi Network using a Windows IoT Background App (task)?

All possible solutions require a foreground app/UI thread (obviously not possible with a pure IoT Background App)

References:
"If it is called from a background task, you will see an "Access Denied" error message or a similar message." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifi.wifiadapter.scanasync

"DeviceUseTrigger cannot be used with in-process background tasks. The info in this topic only applies to background tasks that run out-of-process." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/access-sensors-and-devices-from-a-background-task

Comment: To others, it is **NOT** possible to scan for WiFi networks using a background task (as headless app) with the current Windows 10 IoT Core.  (I'm assuming it is a UWP security issue that makes sense on desktop but none for a headless IoT app). --- The 'solution' is to run the background task from a foreground app.  I assume that causes the background task to run in the UI thread.  Which solves WiFi scanning issues.  (note: I did not notice any performance decrease going from a background app to foreground app wrapper)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WiFiAdapter.ScanAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifi.wifiadapter.scanasync) method does not support in background task, it is by design. I think you can use [Device Portal API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-api-core#networking) to get the available wifi networks information.

Firstly, `/api/wifi/interfaces` can enumerate the available wireless network interfaces, and then

`/api/wifi/networks` can enumerate the list of wireless networks on the specified interface, in this api you can specify the interface with GUID on the request URI.

In this workaround, you need to send http request in the background task. In addition, [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsDevicePortalWrapper) is a client library that wraps the Windows Device Portal REST APIs. Hope that is helpful for you.

You can also post a requirement via Feedback Hub App.The Feedback Hub app lets you tell Microsoft about any problems you run in to while using Windows 10 and send suggestions to help us improve your Windows experience.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this method and I was able to do a successful Wifi Scan through a background task, however, from the /api/wifi/networks response, the Bssid(or Mac-Address) field is missing in all the networks other than the connected network. Is this a known limitation?